# Не удаётся загрузить dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Как исправить такую ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через ссылки пробовал добавить нужную *dll*. Не получается, выдаётся следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы не можете подключить библиотеку, потому что она не является допустимой .NET сборкой. Для работы с неуправляемым кодом из C#-проекта используйте [P/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa288468(v=vs.94)).

Почитайте [документацию](http://ianpr.org/docs/iANPR_en.pdf) вашей библиотеки прежде чем пытаться ее использовать, там есть пример на C#.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека написана не на .NET и не может быть так подключена. Смотрите [пример](http://recog.ru/blog/ianpr/227.html) по работе с ней из .NET.

Comment: Вы имели в виду «**не** на .NET»?

Comment: @VladD Ага. Спасибо. Исправил.